# Complexity of recursive least squares (RLS) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, time-complexity, big-o

Which operation(s) make the complexity of [recursive least squares (RLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) algorithm is equal to O(n^2) and why?

```
% Filter Parameters
p       = 4;                % filter order
lambda  = 1.0;              % forgetting factor
laminv  = 1/lambda;
delta   = 1.0;              % initialization parameter
w       = zeros(p,1);       % filter coefficients
P       = delta*eye(p);     % inverse correlation matrix
e       = x*0;              % error signal
for m = p:length(x)
    % Acquire chunk of data
    y = n(m:-1:m-p+1);
    % Error signal equation
    e(m) = x(m)-w'*y;
    Pi = P*y; % Parameters for efficiency
    % Filter gain vector update
    k = (Pi)/(lambda+y'*Pi);  
    P = (P - k*y'*P)*laminv;  % Inverse correlation matrix update
    w = w + k*e(m);  % Filter coefficients adaption
end
```

[full code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36858-recursive-least-squares-filter)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~tabus/course/ASP/LectureNew10.pdf) paper has a great explanation, here is the relevant section in an image:

[image]

Comment: why 2.1, 2.5 and 2.7 are equal to M^2 flops?